# What do the four coloured areas of this p-value distribution actually represent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, data-visualization, p-value

The chart below shows a distribution of p-values (deep blue and orange areas) given by a data sample that deviates from the null hypothesis, while the grey and light orange areas represent the expected p-values if the null hypothesis was true, and the black line represents the nominal threshold alpha:

[image: p-Model]

Now what I have been struggling to understand, is what each of these four coloured areas actually represent, in terms of probabilities:

**How do these four areas relate to the proportion of false positives and false negatives, etc., or is there no relationship there at all?**

Another way to look at this, is to consider whether the difference between the p-values of a sample distribution and the p-values expected under the null hypothesis has any physical meaning, does it?

Please help clarify, thanks!

**Note:** This question is related to, but different from a previous question, which specifically explores the relationship between this p-value distribution and the PDF/CDF from which it was generated: [What is the link (discrepancy?) between these PDF/CDF and p-value distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205802/what-is-the-link-discrepancy-between-these-pdf-cdf-and-p-value-distributions)

Comment: You might want to add some context (what is the x-axis?) since $p$-values can come from many disparate tests.

Comment: This is a general (hypothetical) question, but fair point: Let's say the x-axis represents 1,000 different and independent experiments to test for potential correlations between different pairs of randomly selected genes within a large population.  Just as an example.

Comment: The correct interpretation of this chart depends somewhat on what this set of p-values is. Could you explain how one obtains a "distribution of p-values" from a single sample? Several methods are possible, such as iterated simulations, bootstrapping from a bivariate dataset, computing all possible correlations in a multivariate dataset, or computing correlations within subsets of a bivariate dataset (determined by the values of a third, categorical, variable).  The interpretations of the resulting sets of p-values are *radically* different.

Comment: Hi Whuber, of the methods you list, I would suggest that "computing all possible correlations in a multivariate dataset" is the most appropriate as it relates to data mining of the human genome.  So in this case, each potential correlation relates to a different pair of variables (genes) to see whether they are truly correlated or independent under the null hypothesis.  Does that make sense?

Comment: FYI, I have cross-referenced a related post to highlight and explain the link, but also the difference between these two questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205802/what-is-the-link-discrepancy-between-these-pdf-cdf-and-p-value-distributions

Comment: Yes, that makes good sense.  It's important to know because in such a circumstance many of the correlation coefficients are interdependent: knowing the correlation between $x$ and $y$ and the correlation between $y$ and $z$ gives you information about the correlation between $x$ and $z$. Thus this "distribution of p-values" should not be analyzed as if it were a collection of *independent* variates (which is usually what is implied in the word "distribution").

Comment: I should also point out that the frequency of each individual variable (e.g., genetic mutation) may be so low, that any such inter-dependency would barely be noticeable.  In other words, finding correlations between $x$ and $y$ and between $y$ and $z$, would not necessarily be picked up as a correlation between $x$ and $z$.  If that makes sense.

Comment: ... so for the sake of this question, can we assume that the correlations are *not* inter-dependent?  In which case, back to the original question: What do the four areas represent?